# How to integrate one webapplication (java) with another webapplication(java/.net.php)?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, web-applications, single-sign-on

I have some doubts regarding web application integration. So Please suggest me possible ways for implementing below functionality.

Lest's say I have one web Application(WebApp1) in Java/.net/PHP and Second web application(WebApp2) in Java. Both web application is deployed on different web servers. and uses the one common database. One web application(WebApp1) has only login form and other web application(WebApp2) has game module. now when User log in from one web Application(WebApp1) with correct credential then it should redirect to other web application(WebApp2).

So Please suggest me how to implement this functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to implement SSO between your .net/php app and java app, one way to do it is using [CAS](https://www.apereo.org/cas) server .
These links may help to get started:
 http://jasig.275507.n4.nabble.com/Single-Sign-On-Between-Java-and-Net-App-td3039830.html 
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Home

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. One more thing, Is it possible using websocket ?

Comment: But for my second web application(WebApp2), use web socket to send user and password data to another webservice module. so do you think sso will work ?

Comment: is that a third party webservice module ?